# Is Muhammad the firstborn of creation?

Tags: allah, prophet-muhammad, islamic-philosophy, creation, metaphysical

I have heard some state that the light of Muhammad was the first creation of Allah and that everything else was created from Muhammad's light. Is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of Mohamed pbuh being the first creation of Allah or Mohamed pbuh was created from the nur of Allah is a doctrine of sufis, proposed by [Sayyid Abdul Qadir Gilani](https://sufiwiki.com/content/abdul_qadir_jilani/).

This concept is narrated with the following ["Hadith of Jabir"](https://www.livingislam.org/fiqhi/fiqha_e30.html) :

> It is related that Jabir ibn ʿAbd Allah said to the Prophet ﷺ : "O Messenger of Allah, may my father and mother be sacrificed for you, tell me of the first thing Allah created before all things." He said: "O Jabir, the first thing Allah created was the light of your Prophet from His light, and that light remained (lit. "turned") in the midst of His Power for as long as He wished, and there was not, at that time, a Tablet or a Pen or a Paradise or a Fire or an angel or a heaven or an earth. And when Allah wished to create creation, he divided that Light into four parts and from the first made the Pen, from the second the Tablet, from the third the Throne, [and from the fourth everything else]."

### THIS NARRATION GOES AGAINST QURAN

This narration is against the teaching of Quran.

> قُلْ إِنَّمَآ أَنَا۠ بَشَرٌ مِّثْلُكُمْ يُوحَىٰٓ إِلَىَّ أَنَّمَآ إِلَـٰهُكُمْ إِلَـٰهٌ وَٰحِدٌ ۖ فَمَن كَانَ يَرْجُوا۟ لِقَآءَ رَبِّهِۦ فَلْيَعْمَلْ عَمَلًا صَـٰلِحًا وَلَا يُشْرِكْ بِعِبَادَةِ رَبِّهِۦٓ أَحَدًۢا
>
> Say, ˹O Prophet,˺ “I am only a man like you, ˹but˺ it has been revealed to me that your God is only One God. So whoever hopes for the meeting with their Lord, let them do good deeds and associate none in the worship of their Lord.”

**Here the word bashr/بَشَرٌ means human.**

*For a more detailed answer check : [Was the Prophet Created From Light?](https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/4509)*

### THIS NARRATION IS NOT LOGICAL

*This narration can also be debunked by saying that if Allah is one/ahad, how can he/his light be divided into parts?*